# inserindo imagem no banco mysql

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, query, longblob

Se eu quiser inserir uma imagem no banco basta usar a seguinte query:

```
INSERT INTO teste (Id_Blob,Na_Imagem) VALUES (1,LOAD_FILE("C://imagem.png"));
```

se eu quiser inserir uma imagem que estar em outro computador na rede, como varia isso? Estou tentando usar o seguinte código.

```
INSERT INTO teste (Id_Blob,Na_Imagem) VALUES (1,LOAD_FILE("///10.1.1.10//Fotos//2.png"));
```

Mas o campo da imagem **longblob** fica vazio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvi meu problema com uma **POG** (kkkk) não é a melhor forma, mas resolveu. Usei o `**File.Copy()**`, copiei o arquivo da maquina virtual para a local (onde está rodando a aplicação). Criei uma variável para armazenar o caminho do arquivo salvo na maquina local. e usei o comando:
 `INSERT INTO teste (Id_Blob,Na_Imagem) VALUES (1,LOAD_FILE("VariavelCaminho"));`

**Caso alguém tenha uma outra solução por favor compartilhe**
Esse link "**[Salvar Imagem no Mysql](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/deepak.sharma00/how-to-save-images-in-mysql-database-using-C-Sharp/)**" ensina fazer isso, mas particularmente não consegui fazer, pois trabalho com classes, e tenho uma classe para conexão com o banco. É isso ai. #POG na cabeça